# Root protected synced directories

Tags: permissions, directory, sync

I recently synced a directory on my file system with my OneDrive account, using `onedrived`. The program itself functions correctly, but when the files are delivered to my pc I can't access the files or directories synced with OneDrive, without using sudo.

Is there any way I could setup the parent directory to force all sub directories to be accessible by non-root users?

I can unlock the files by doing `sudo chmod a+rwx *` but this is a bit of a pain. I'd like a setup to automatically unlock the directories.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generic method would be to change the owner and group of the directory where those files are stored to your username and group.

Mind though that I would have expected the location already to be set like that: I would expect onedrive to install in your home directory into `$HOME/OneDrive`

So it would be from command line

```
cd ~
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER OneDrive
```